# Can I reduce one strip() call from this list comprehension?

Tags: python

```
[x.strip() for x in multi.splitlines() if len(x.strip()) > 0]
```

I was wondering if it was possible to rewrite this list comprehension using only one `.strip()` call.  This construction requires me to call it twice.

I couldn't figure out a way to get the `strip()` inside the `multi.splitlines()` operation, as that's working on lists

It's not a performance-critical issue, but just wondered if i could make this an even leaner statement.

Comment: What's `trim()`? I'm guessing you meant `strip()`?

Comment: @DavidZ Yeah,  I meant strip()

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str.isspace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace) in the filter instead which checks if the string contains only whitespace characters:

```
[x.strip() for x in multi.splitlines() if x and not x.isspace()]
```

`str.isspace` is also **faster** since it does not create a new string only to check its length.

Alternatively, you could first strip the string and then keep non-empty ones:

```
[x for x in map(str.strip, multi.splitlines()) if x]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `filter`:

```
filter(len, [x.strip() for x in lines])
```

This will achieve the same thing as you want: It will first strip all characters, then it will remove empty strings.

Comment: Beware that `filter` returns an iterator in Python 3, not a list like it returned in Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are creating a list comprehension from the results of a computation that you also want to use in a condition, a good general approach is to use a generator to perform the computation. In your case, the computation is `strip()` so you'd start with a generator that strips whitespace off the strings:

```
(x.strip() for x in multi.splitlines())
```

and then you can build your list comprehension on that:

```
[y for y in (x.strip() for x in multi.splitlines()) if len(y) > 0]
```

In this case, `strip()` is a simple enough computation that it doesn't really matter if you use this method, but it can come in handy when your computation takes a long time and/or a lot of resources and you don't want to do it more than once per element.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to nest another comprehension or generator expression inside your current one. The outer one will assign a name to the values yielded by the inner expression, so you won't need duplicated expressions (such as method calls):

```
[x for x in (y.strip() for y in multi.splitlines()) if x]
```

Note that I'm using `if x` instead of `if len(x) > 0`. In this context they mean exactly the same thing.